# Simple T-SQL function to convert date to displayable format

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a strange bug that I cannot resolve (with a one line function).

This code works:

```
DECLARE @TestDate datetime = '2013-05-01 23:15:11'
select IsNull(convert(varchar(max), @TestDate, 120), 'null') as 'test1'
```

Displays: `2013-05-01 23:15:11`

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DateOrNullToChar] (@InputDate date)
RETURNS VARCHAR(40)
BEGIN
   return ISNULL(convert(varchar(40),@InputDate, 120),'null'); 
END
select dbo.DateOrNullToChar('2013-05-01 23:15:11') as 'result'
```

Returns: `2013-05-01`   (no time)

I have also tried `varchar(max)`.

The purpose of the function is for something like this:

```
Set @ErrorMessage = ' @ArrivalDate=' + dbo.DateOrNullToChar(@ArrivalDate) + 
                    ' @DepartureDate=' + dbo.DateOrNullToChar(@DepartureDate);
```

If any one value is null, the whole value becomes null. So I want to see the string 'null' when a date has a null value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@InputDate should be datetime or datetime2 if you want time to be shown

The clues are in the code...

- @TestDate datetime
- @InputDate date

Comment: Oh, that was so obvious - but I missed it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the parameter type to be datetime instead of date:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DateOrNullToChar] (@InputDate datetime)
```

It's silently converting the string to your date parameter type and thus dropping the time portion.